# Ошибка streamlit, optuna

Tags: python, optuna

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку в streamlit?
Модель LGBM, бинарный классификатор. Для регрессии такой ошибки нет. Необходимо указать параметр direction в create study или дело в plotly? Как правильно? В юпитере выводится график, в стримлит ошибка.

код стримлит

```
     fig = plot_optimization_history(study)
     st.plotly_chart(fig))
```

ошибка AttributeError: 'Study' object has no attribute '_directions'

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/frontend/main.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
File "/app/frontend/main.py", line 227, in main
    page_names_to_funcs[selected_page]()
File "/app/frontend/main.py", line 174, in training
    start_training(config=config, endpoint=endpoint)
File "/app/frontend/src/train/training.py", line 64, in start_training
    fig_imp = plot_param_importances(study)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/visualization/_param_importances.py", line 139, in plot_param_importances
    importances_info = _get_importances_info(study, evaluator, params, target, target_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/visualization/_param_importances.py", line 41, in _get_importances_info
    _check_plot_args(study, target, target_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/visualization/_utils.py", line 60, in _check_plot_args
    if target is None and any(study._is_multi_objective() for study in studies):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/visualization/_utils.py", line 60, in <genexpr>
    if target is None and any(study._is_multi_objective() for study in studies):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 1022, in _is_multi_objective
    return len(self.directions) > 1
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 207, in directions
    return self._directions
```

Comment: Нужен не только стэктрэйс, но и текст ошибки. Также нужен ваш код.

Comment: Да, вы что-то трейс так обрезали, что ошибки то самой в нём и не осталось.

Answer (score 0):

Optuna, используемая в вашем коде для оптимизации параметров модели LGBM (LightGBM), ожидает, что вы укажете направление оптимизации (direction) для вашего объекта study в случае бинарной классификации.
Для бинарной классификации direction может быть установлен в 'maximize' или 'minimize' в зависимости от того, какую метрику вы пытаетесь оптимизировать.
Например, если вы оптимизируете площадь под ROC-кривой (AUC-ROC), то 'maximize' будет соответствовать лучшему значению метрики.

```
# Создание study с указанием направления (например, 'maximize' для AUC-ROC)
study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')

# Запуск оптимизации
study.optimize(objective_function, n_trials=100)

# Где objective_function - ваша функция, которую вы оптимизируете
```

И соответственно если целевая метрика должна быть минимизирована (например, log loss) нужно заменить 'maximize' на 'minimize'.

Comment: direction указано.
проблема в выводе 
    fig = plot_optimization_history(study)
    st.plotly_chart(fig))
вот собственно и весь проблемный код.
в ю.ноутбуке график выводится, в стримлит ошибка.

Comment: в самой модели всё верно указано, подозреваю, что дело  в plotly.
изначально 
study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize", study_name="LGB")

Comment: [Завязывайте с GPT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)